# Preventing objects from being linked if they are not needed?

Tags: c++, optimization, linker, makefile, arm

I have an ARM project that I'm building with make. I'm creating the list of object files to link based on the names of all of the .c and .cpp files in my source directory. However, I would like to exclude objects from being linked if they are never used. Will the linker exclude these objects from the .elf file automatically even if I include them in the list of objects to link? If not, is there a way to generate a list of only the objects that need to be linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RealView, it seems that it is possible.  This section discusses it:

3.3.3 Unused section elimination

Unused section elimination removes code that is never executed, or data that is not 
referred to by the code, from the final image. This optimization can be controlled by the 
--remove, --no_remove, --first, --last, and --keep linker options. Use the --info unused 
linker option to instruct the linker to generate a list of the unused sections that have been 
eliminated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to compile your code differently to strip out function and data that isn't used.  Usually all the objects are compiled into the same symbol, so they can't be individually omitted if they're not used.

Add the two following switches to your compiler line:
`-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`
When you compile, the compiler will now put individual functions and data into their own sections instead of lumping them all in one module section.

Then, in your linker, specify the following:
`--gc-sections`
This instructs the linker to remove unused sections ("gc" is for garbage collection).  It will garbage collect parts of files and entire files.  For example, if you're compiling an object, but only use 1 function of 100 in the object, it will toss out the other 99 you're not using.

If you run into issues with functions not found (it happens due to various reasons like externs between libraries), you can use `.keep` directives in your linker file (`*.ld`) in order to prevent garbage collection on those individual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Like many people said, the answer is "depends".  In my experience, RVCT is very good about dead code stripping.  Unused code and data will almost always be removed in the final link stage.  GCC, on the other hand (at least without the LLVM back end), is rather poor at whole image static analysis and will not do a very good job at removing unused code (and woe be it to you if your code is in different sections requiring long jumps).  You can take some steps to mitigate it, such as using function-sections, which creates a separate section for each function and enables some better dead code stripping.

Have your linker generate a map file of your binary so you can see what made it in there and what got stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the sophistication of the compiler/linker and optimization level, the linker will not link in code that isn't being called.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler/linker are you using?  Some linkers do this automatically, and some provide the feature as a command-line option.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, many compilers will not include unused code on an object file basis.  Some may not have this resolution and will include entire libraries ("because this makes the build process faster").

For example, given a file `junk.c` and it has three functions:  `Func1`, `Func2` and `Func3`.  The build process creates an object file, `junk.o`, which has all three functions in it.  If function `Func2` is not used, it will be included anyway because the linker can't exclude one function out of an object file.

On the other hand, given files: `Func1.c`, `Func2.c`, and `Func3.c`, with the functions above, one per file. If `Func2` in `Func2.c` is not used, the linker will not include it.

Some linkers are intelligent enough to exclude files out of libraries.  However, each linker is different on its granularity of file inclusion (and thus file exclusion).  Read your linker's manual or contact their customer support for exact information.

I suggest moving the suspect functions into a separate file (one function per file) and rebuild.  Measure the code size before and after.  Also, there may be a difference between Debug and Release linking.  The Debug linking could be lazy and just throw everything in while the Release linking puts more effort into removing unused code.

Just my thoughts and experience, Your Mileage May Vary (YMMV).

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally linkers link in all object files that are explicity specified in the command line, even if they could be left out and the program would not have any unresolved symbols. This means that you can deliberately change the behaviour of a program by including an object file that does something triggered from static initialization but is not called directly or indirectly from `main`.

Typically if you place most of your object files in a static library and link this library with a single object file containing your entry point the linker will only pick out members of the library (iteratively) that help resolve an unresolved symbol reference in the original object file or one included subsequently because it resolved a previous unresolved symbol.

In short, place most of your object files in a library and just link this with one object containing your entry point.